# Do CSS resets like normalize.css propagate to the shadow dom?

Tags: css, polymer, reset, shadow-dom

Do CSS resets like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) propagate to the shadow dom?  So for example if [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is used in a [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) application/project, will all the element throughout the dom and shadow dom have the normalize.css resets applied?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: Why not test it and find out?

Comment: The main problem with that will be `css` file. Polymer has deprecated usage of external css files in its elements and normalize is an external css file

Comment: There is a tool to create a style module from external styles.

Comment: Not exactly a tool but a web-service [Polystyles](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polystyles) from PolymerLabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (unless they are inherited by default).

Because the Shadow DOM isolates the CSS styles from the one of the main document, nothing defined in normalize.css will be taken in account in your Shadow DOM.

Comment: ... except when you add it to your components style

Comment: According to @ebidel CSS properties that inherit continue to inherit inside the shadow dom.  Supersharp do you want to update the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.

You can use `all: initial;` to reset all your styles inside the component.

"...rules in the parent page have higher specificity than :host,... this allows users to override your top-level styling from the outside."

So if you set styles on your `:root` or `html` will get into the shadowDOM